# How can i leave a room when my game is finnished - Google Play Services - Android

Tags: android, android-gps

I've successfully integrated GPS realtime multiplayer into my game & it's working good.

Though. When a game is finished, players stays connected to each other..

How can i disconnect a player manually from the game?

So when the game is finished, the player will disconnect from the room by pressing for example "back to menu".

/
Martin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just solved by checking if room is active.

```
if (mRoomID != null) {
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, mRoomID);
    mRoomID = null;

}
```